# Python print something on a specific day

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to create a python code that can print messages on specific days for example something like that:

```
if day == 27.07:

   print("Happy Birthday")
```

I thank you for any help

Comment: What have you tried? Are you just having formatting issues? The docs give you some good examples on how to get similar results to match your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```py
from datetime import datetime
birthday = '26.07'
if datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m') == birthday:
    print("Happy Birthday")
```

Docs:

- [`datetime.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today)
- [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
if today == "2022-07-26":
  print("Happy Birthday")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this for a particular day as mentioned above or a range of days if required.

**1. For only One day**

Taking a specific date for example "26/07/1999" and lets print happy birthday if today coincides with our specific day.

```
from datetime import datetime

birthday = "26/07/1999"

BRDAY = datetime.strptime(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')

Today = datetime.now()

if(BRDAY.day == Today.day and BRDAY.month == Today.month):
    print("Happy Birthday ")
```

**2. For Multiple days**

Say, we have a list of days "1/07/1922","15/07/1922","22/07/1922" and "26/07/1922" and we have to print something on those days then we can try:

```
from datetime import datetime

Days = ["1/07/1922","15/07/1922","22/07/1922","26/07/1922"]
BRDAY=[]

for i in range(len(Days)):
    var=Days[i]
    BRDAY.append(datetime.strptime(var, '%d/%m/%Y'))

Today = datetime.now()



for i in range(len(Days)):
    if(BRDAY[i].day == Today.day and BRDAY[i].month == Today.month):
        print("Happy Birthday ")
```

**3. To find if there is a specific day in a list of days**

Say we have to **search for "15/07/1922"** in the **list of ["1/07/1922","15/07/1922","22/07/1922","26/07/1922"]** and if found, python will print **Found**, we can try the following:

```
SPECIFIC="15/07/1922"
SPECIFIC=datetime.strptime(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')
        
for i in range(len(Days)):
    if(SPECIFIC.day == BRDAY[i].day and BRDAY[i].month == SPECIFIC.month):
        print("Found")
```

Run the full program step by step, you'll get it. Happy Testing!